# Descargar un archivo en cliente desde el servidor Asp.net despues de un __doPostback()

Tags: javascript, c#, html5, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo un enlace en la parte del cliente con la etiqueta "a href" donde al pulsarlo hace un __doPostBack() al servidor para que desde alli genere un archivo .pdf y luego desde el mismo servidor lance la petición de descarga. En la descarga no puede verse información desde que url o carpeta se esta cargando, ni tampoco debe borrar la pagina actual donde he lanzado la petición.
El problema es que el código no funciona.

Desde el cliente:

```
<a href = '#' style = 'cursor: pointer' runat = 'server' onclick=' __doPostBack(\"DescargarPDF\", \" " + iemID1.Value + "," + itemID2.Value + " \" ); '>Descargar</a>"
```

En servidor:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + archivoDestino);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length",System.IO.Path.GetFileName(rutaDestino).Length.ToString());
Response.TransmitFile(rutaDestino);
Response.End();
```

He probado metiendo este código dentro de un Download.ashx pasandole 2 parametros: nombre y longitud para luego abrirlo desde el cliente con un open.window() De esta manera funciona pero me abre otra ventana de navegador en blanco con un tamaño, sin visualizar el pdf y ademas se ve en la url informacion desde donde se descarga: Download.ashx?par1=miarchivo.pdf&par2=5000.

Necesito que la descarga se haga desde la misma pagina y sin que se vea la url desde donde se descarga !! O en otro caso que se pudiera visualizar el pdf en otra pestaña del navegador para que luego el usuario se la descargue si lo necesita.

Comment: Me falta información para poder ayudarte pero si se que el Content-Length lo estás cubriendo mal ya que debería ser el tamaño en bytes del fichero en vez del número de caracteres del nombre del fichero. Yo creo que esa línea puedes borrarla ya que el TransmitFile ya la cubre por ti.

Comment: @bsebe Que información necesitas mas? El problema es que cuando la pagina se ha renderizado y mas tarde con el enlace hago un __doPostBack() a un metodo con el codigo del servidor que he puesto no funciona. En cambio si el codigo lo pongo justo al empezar en el Load() si que me lo ejecuta.

Comment: Me falta código y me falta práctica con los aspx ya que hace mucho que solo trabajo con mvc. De todas formas te he escrito una respuesta de como lo veo yo. Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Hace muchos años que no toco un aspx y estoy muy oxidado. No entiendo tu código para llamar al postback, jamas lo hice así. Yo creo que el problema está precisamente en que esa llamada no se está haciendo.

Tal como lo haría yo sería algo tan sencillo como esto:

```
<a id="btnDescargar" style='cursor: pointer' runat="server" data-item1="value" data-item2="value">Descargar</a>
```

En los data-item tienes que poner los valores que necesitas pasarle a tu método.
Y, luego, en el .cs:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnDescargar.ServerClick += BtnDescargar_ServerClick;
    }
    
    private void BtnDescargar_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlAnchor enlace = (HtmlAnchor)sender;

        var valor1 = enlace.Attributes["data-item1"];
        var valor2 = enlace.Attributes["data-item2"];

        string rutaDestino = ObtenerNombreFichero(valor1, valor2);
        var archivoDestino = Path.GetFileName(rutaDestino);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + archivoDestino);

        Response.TransmitFile(rutaDestino);
        Response.End();
    }

    private string ObtenerNombreFichero(string valor1, string valor2)
    {
        return @"c:\temp\fondo.pdf";
    }
}
```

El inline puedes cambiarlo por attachment tal como tenias en tu código. Es para mostrar que no cambia la url de la página.